# Generate dummy images local via CLI

Tags: php, imagemagick, command-line-interface

I need to generate some (thousands) dummy images local to test a CLI based content converter. The file names are set.

A name list as example:

```
fw4df.jpg
antotherName.jpg
```

and so on.

I would write a script using `ImageMagick` extension to create those images with some dummy content.

Any suggestion to solve this more clever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this for 1,000 images:

```
head -1000 /path/to/your/word/list | 
   while read word; do                              \ 
      echo -n $word | convert label:@- "$word.jpg"  \
   done
```

You get

[image]

Comment: ty for your answer. How should be /usr/share/dict/words look like?

Comment: It's a simple dictionary of 500,000 words, arranged one word per line. Yours may be in a different location, try `locate words` or `find  /usr  -name  words`.

Comment: ok, ty! Now i got it. That in my case the file names are fixed defined you didn't recognized, correct?

Comment: So just use your list of filenames instead of the dictionary.

Comment: yep, of corurse, i tried. but the naming seems to be randomized.. like: `$ head -2 ./test.txt | ..`

Comment: Delete the line that says `word=$(...)` if you have your own filenames.

Comment: great! ty very much. I will edit & accepted your answer. Last question: Is it possible to set the output image dimensions with this solution?

Comment: Of course! You can set the background yellow with `-background yellow`, the text red with `-fill red` and the image size with `-size 300x200`... specified  **before** `-label`.

Comment: Awesome! ty and have great day!

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick ships with some built in images. The most common ones are `wizard:`, `rose:`, and `logo:`

```
convert wizard: wizard.jpg
```

[image: wizard]

```
convert rose: rose.jpg
```

[image: rose]

```
convert logo: logo.jpg
```

[image: logo]

### Edit

If you just want a clever PHP function, I would continue to use PseudoImages to simplify everything.

```php
function createPseudoImage($label_text, $width, $height, $label_format='No. %d') {
  $background = new Imagick;
  $background->newPseudoImage($width, $height, 'PATTERN:HORIZONTALSAW');

  $label = new Imagick();
  $label->setBackgroundColor('transparent');
  $label_width = $background->getImageWidth() * 0.8;
  $label_height = $background->getImageHeight() * 0.8;
  $label_text = sprintf('CAPTION:'.$label_format, $label_text);
  $label->newPseudoImage($label_width, $label_height, $label_text);
  $offset_x = $background->getImageWidth()/2 - $label->getImageWidth()/2;
  $offset_y = $background->getImageHeight()/2 - $label->getImageHeight()/2;
  $background->compositeImage($label, Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP, $offset_x, $offset_y);
  return $background;
}

$fpo = createPseudoImage(49, 500, 200);
$fpo->writeImage('/tmp/out.png');
```

[image: No. 49]

But YMMV

Comment: ty for your note! But the content doesn't matter that much. I just wrote a script that write some identifying text to images.

Comment: ty for your edit. I will vote up for it (: .. but the accepted answer hit it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script based on the PHP doc example. Perhaps it will help someone:

```
<?php

generateDummyImages(array("test.jpg", "test2.jpg"));

/**
 * 
 * @param array $files
 * @param string $dataOutPath
 */
function generateDummyImages($files, $dataOutPath = "") {
    $width                      = 500;
    $height                     = 500;
    $imageCompressionQuality    = 90;

    foreach($files as $i => $filename) {
        /* Create a new imagick object */
        $im = new Imagick();

        /* Create new image. This will be used as fill pattern */
        $im->newPseudoImage($width, $height, "gradient:red-black");

        /* Create imagickdraw object */
        $draw = new ImagickDraw();

        /* Start a new pattern called "gradient" */
        $draw->pushPattern('typo', 0, 0, $width, $height);

        /* Composite the gradient on the pattern */
        $draw->composite(Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0, $width, $height, $im);

        /* Close the pattern */
        $draw->popPattern();

        /* Use the pattern called "gradient" as the fill */
        $draw->setFillPatternURL('#typo');

        /* Set font size to 52 */
        $draw->setFontSize(100);

        /* Annotate some text */
        $draw->annotation($width / 2 - 100, $height / 2, "No. " . $i);

        /* Create a new canvas object and a white image */
        $canvas = new Imagick();
        $canvas->newImage($width, $height, "white");

        /* Draw the ImagickDraw on to the canvas */
        $canvas->drawImage($draw);

        /* 1px black border around the image */
        $canvas->borderImage('black', 1, 1);

        /* Set the format to PNG */
        $canvas->setImageFormat('jpg');
        $canvas->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
        $canvas->setCompressionQuality($imageCompressionQuality);

        /* Output the image */
        $canvas->writeimage($dataOutPath . $filename);
        echo "Image generated: " . $dataOutPath . $filename . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

?>
```